# Microserviços com Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, microsserviços

Comecei a desenvolver uma aplicação utilizando o conceito de *microservices* e ainda tenho muitas dúvidas. Eu tenho repositórios e suas respectivas entidades, os envios das requisições funcionam corretamente porém quando finalizo a aplicação e início denovo perco os dados.
 Por exemplo, eu envio um `post` que salva os dados no banco, dou `get` e obtenho corretamente porém se eu reiniciar a aplicação o meu `get` não retorna **nada**. 
Por que isso ocorre? Como faço para obter todos os dados?

Repositório

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "veiculos", path = "veiculos")
public interface VeiculoRepository extends MongoRepository<Veiculo, String> {
    Veiculo save(Veiculo veiculo);

    List<Veiculo> findAll();

}
```

Application.properties

```
spring.application.name=VeiculoService

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost:27017/db

spring.data.rest.baseUri=/api

spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.enabled=true
spring.http.encoding.force=true
spring.http.gzip.enabled=true


management.context-path=/actuator

info.app.name=Db Admin
info.app.description=DB
info.app.version=${project.version}

server.port=${port:8181}
server.servletPath=/
```

Comment: Está usando o `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` é? Teria como atualizar com o seu `application.properties`, se estiver usando? Outra coisa, tem alguma configuração customizada?

Comment: Uau, reparei agora que há uma configuração do Fongo, o mongoDB em memória.

Comment: Exatamente, por padrão é sempre em memória, quando você não configurar um servidor seu, há no *boot* algo *embedded* para tudo =D Veja se consegue configurar, se não, atualize com suas dúvidas :)

Comment: Aproveitando, há uso do Spring REST e qualquer post, get, delete etc caem nestes repositórios. É possível desviar para a API e depois chamar o repositório? Ou este não é o propósito?

Comment: Isto é porque está usando `spring-data-rest`, então são publicados recursos HTTP para cada repositório. Para usar como falou, use repositório normal (`@Repository`) e os controladores, da mesma forma que no Spring MVC (`@Controller` ou `@RestController`)

Comment: Perfeito, obrigada! Se puder publicar na forma de resposta

Comment: OK, logo logo respondo incluindo referências =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando usamos o `spring-boot`, por padrão há algo [*embedded*/*in-memory*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-auto-configuration) para quase tudo, desde *containers*, serviços de mensageria e bancos de dados, que é este caso. Devido a isto você consegue incluir e recuperar dados em uma execução, mas ao reiniciar o banco é removido (por padrão será sempre `create-drop` nas bases em memória, independente se SQL ou NoSQL).

Para MongoDB não há, inclusive, se você gerar pelo http://start.spring.io/ ou usar o auto configure padrão, mas como bem observou, está configurado o [`Fongo`](https://github.com/fakemongo/fongo) para ser o seu *servidor* Mongo, ou seja, está usando um bando *in-memory*. Não sei se está seguindo algum tutorial ou alguma aplicação gerada para referência, mas ela deve ter incluído configuração para gerar uma instância [`Mongo`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/Mongo.html) ou [`MongoClient`](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html)

Por exemplo no caso de estar usando MongoDB e `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` irá habilitar o [`MongoDataAutoConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoDataAutoConfiguration.html), já que o `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` irá incluir dependências do MongoDB (`Mongo` e `MongoTemplate`). Isto acontece devido ao [`@ConditionalOnClass`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnClass.html) existente na configuração (`@ConditionalOnClass({ Mongo.class, MongoTemplate.class})`).

Para configurar um servidor, fazendo com que sua base não fique em memória, você pode configurar a propriedade `spring.data.mongodb.uri` OU as que são específicas para *host* e porta, `spring.data.mongodb.host` e `spring.data.mongodb.port`, respectivamente, no seu arquivo `application.properties`/`application.yml`. [Aqui](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) você poderá ver todas as propriedades que poderá usar no *boot*, não só apenas as relacionadas com o Mongo.

Já quanto à sua dúvida quanto as requisições HTTP que eram tratadas no repositório, isto é devido ao fato de estar usando [`spring-data-rest`](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-rest/), veja que seu repositório está anotado com [`@RepositoryRestResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/rest/core/annotation/RepositoryRestResource.html), então `RepositoryRestConfiguration` irá agir e expor os recursos HTTP através do repositório.

Para usar como você necessita, separando as responsabilidades entre *controller* e *repository*, você pode usar repositório normal do `spring-data` (`@Repository` ou nada, mas continue herdando de `MongoRepository`) e os controladores como no Spring MVC (`@Controller` ou `@RestController`), daí nos controladores recupera uma instância do(s) repositório(s) que necessitar.

Comment: Você é um dos poucos que encontrei aqui no SOpt que entendem sobre Spring, se puder me ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74631/requisi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-api-rest