# Requisições para API Rest

Tags: java, api, spring, spring-data

A aplicação utiliza *Spring Rest* na qual os paths de um CRUD são gerados automaticamente para cada entidade, tenho as entidades Veículo, Contato e Agência e cada uma com seu respectivo repositório.

Veículo possui como atributo uma lista de Agência e uma lista de Contato, os paths são gerados:

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl http://localhost:8181/api
{
  "_links" : {
    "agencias" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/agencias{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "veiculos" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "contatos" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/contatos{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/alps"
    }
  }
}
```

Criei um objeto Veículo mas só consigo passar `nome` e `tipo`

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6
{
  "nome" : "veiculo",
  "tipo" : "tipo",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6"
    },
    "contatos" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6/contatos"
    },
    "agencias" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6/agencias"
    }
  }
}
```

Isso ocorre quando tento enviar uma Array:

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"nome": "teste", "tipo": "tipo", "agencias": [{"nome": "agencia"}]}' http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos
{"cause":{"cause":{"cause":null,"message":"Template must not be null or empty!"},"message":"Template must not be null or empty! (through reference chain: oknok.entities.Veiculo[\"agencias\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])"},"message":"Could not read JSON: Template must not be null or empty! (through reference chain: oknok.entities.Veiculo[\"agencias\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Template must not be null or empty! (through reference chain: oknok.entities.Veiculo[\"agencias\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])"}
```

Consigo executar todas as requisições para */api/veiculo/{id}* porém **não sei como inserir uma lista** de agências e de contatos.
Minha dúvida é: pelo padrão *REST*, **todo CRUD referente a contatos e agencias devem ser feitos nesta path**, *api/veiculos/{id}/contatos* e *api/veiculos/{id}/agencias*, que foi gerada pois irá redirecionar todas as requisições para os seus respectivos repositórios, correto? Portanto, como faço para criar a minha lista de Agências e de Contatos?

Eu não consigo dar PUT, mas somente POST e GET nestes paths, tentei enviar um POST com um JSON que possui um Array, mas quando dou GET não é exibido

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6/agencias
  {
    "_links" : {
      "self" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6/agencias"
      }
    },
    "_embedded" : {
      "agencias" : [ ]
    }
  }

daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl-i -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"agencias": [{"nome": "um"}]}' http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6/agencias
  HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
  Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
  Pragma: no-cache
  Expires: 0
  X-Frame-Options: DENY
  Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 14:34:11 GMT

daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6/agencias
  {
    "_links" : {
      "self" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a50d42ccf2bc55501419d6/agencias"
      }
    },
    "_embedded" : {
      "agencias" : [ ]
    }
  }
```

Minhas entidades são estas (ocultei os getters e setters) com seus repositórios:

`Veiculo`

```
@Document
public class Veiculo {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String nome;

    private String tipo;

    @DBRef
    List<Contato> contatos;

    @DBRef
    List<Agencia> agencias;

}
```

`Veiculo Repository`

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "veiculos", path = "veiculos")
public interface VeiculoRepository extends MongoRepository<Veiculo, String> {
    Veiculo save(Veiculo veiculo);

    List<Veiculo> findAll();
}
```

`Agencia`

```
@Document
public class Agencia {

    @Id
    String id;
    String nome;

    @CreatedBy
    String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    String lastModifiedBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    Date createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
    Date lastModified;

}
```

`Agencia Repository`

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "agencias", path = "agencias")
public interface AgenciaRepository extends MongoRepository<Agencia, String> {

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    Agencia save(Agencia t);
    List<Agencia> findAll();

}
```

`Contato`

```
@Document
public class Contato {

    @Id
    private String id;

    String nome;

    List<Info> dados;

    @DBRef
    Agencia agencia;

}
```

`Contato Repository`

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "contatos", path = "contatos")
public interface ContatoRepository extends MongoRepository<Contato, String> {

    List<Contato> findByNome(@Param("nome") String nome);
    List<Contato> findByAgencia(@Param("agencia") String agencia);

}
```

****UPDATE**
Consegui enviar um Array adicionando a anotação `@RestResource(exported = false)` nos atributos que são listas em Veículo, porém:
I. esse dado não está "relacional" 
II. Se eu criar uma agência em *api/agencias* e depois pegar esse ID para atualizar as agências em *api/veiculos* ele não reconhece a referência. 
Como soluciono isso?

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"nome": "teste", "tipo": "tipo", "agencias": [{"nome": "agencia"}]}' http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos
{"timestamp":1437133673823,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException","message":"Cannot create a reference to an object with a NULL id.","path":"/api/veiculos"}daniela.morais@tusk:~$ ^C
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"nome": "teste", "tipo": "tipo", "agencias": [{"nome": "agencia", "id": "1"}]}' http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos
{
  "nome" : "teste",
  "tipo" : "tipo",
  "contatos" : null,
  "agencias" : [ {
    "nome" : "agencia",
    "createdBy" : null,
    "lastModifiedBy" : null,
    "createdAt" : null,
    "lastModified" : null
  } ],
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a8eb8544ae13951d3f2b6f"
    },
    "agencia" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55a8eb8544ae13951d3f2b6f/agencia"
    }
  }
}
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl http://localhost:8181/api/agencias
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/agencias"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "agencias" : [ ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 0,
    "totalPages" : 0,
    "number" : 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Foi bem difícil eu conseguir resolver meu problema porque não tinha conhecimento necessário para lidar com *Spring Data Rest*, então vou explicar detalhadamente:

## *Spring Data Rest*


O Spring Data Rest é usado para facilitar o desenvolvimento de [API's RestFul](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/45783/o-que-%C3%A9-rest-e-restful) e permitir que o foco seja apenas no desenvolvimento da lógica do negócio pois nos evita de repetições ao desenvolver uma API, apenas com a criação de entidades e de uma interface do seu respectivo repositório ele mapeia os paths e direciona os metódos PUT, POST, GET, PATCH etc. para os respectivos metódos. Tudo isso ocorre sem que a necessidade de praticamente desenvolver **nenhum** código.

Exemplo

Repositório

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "contatos", path = "contatos")
public interface ContatoRepository extends MongoRepository<Contato, String> {

    List<Contato> findByNome(@Param("nome") String nome);
    List<Contato> findByAgencia(@Param("agencia") String agencia);

}
```

Entidade sem getters e setters

```
@Document
public class Contato {

    @Id
    private String id;
    String nome;
    List<Info> dados;
    @DBRef
    Agencia agencia;

}
```

Apenas com essas classes acima, o Spring já possibilita que eu faça as requisições e direciona para o metódo responsável:

```
daniela@daniela-tars:~/microservices$ curl -i -X OPTIONS localhost:8181/api/contatos
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Allow: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sat, 18 Jul 2015 19:43:48 GMT
```

## *HATEOAS*


HATEOAS ou Hypermedia as the Engine of Application State é considerado o melhor ponto de amadurecimento de uma API pois possibilita uma navegação mais fácil entre os recursos da API. Quando é enviado uma requisição como POST, GET e PUT, estas as quais retornam informações, junto com o JSON é retornado uma informação sobre o que mais é possível fazer.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo, junto com o retorno da listagem de todos veículos obtenho a URI dos veículos. Ou seja, posso executar uma requisição para aquela URI. Se enviar um GET para um veículo específico, obtenho a URI de  veículo contatos e agências, as quais também posso acessar e assim por diante:

```
daniela@daniela-tars:~/microservices/microservices$ curl localhost:8181/api/veiculos
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "veiculos" : [ {
      "nome" : "veiculo",
      "tipo" : "tipo",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55aaa7d644aeceb9f439c504"
        },
        "contatos" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55aaa7d644aeceb9f439c504/contatos"
        },
        "agencias" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55aaa7d644aeceb9f439c504/agencias"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
  "page" : {
    "size" : 20,
    "totalElements" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "number" : 0
  }
}daniela@daniela-tars:~644aeceb9f439c504croservices$ curl http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55aaa7d644aeceb9f439c504 
{
  "nome" : "veiculo",
  "tipo" : "tipo",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55aaa7d644aeceb9f439c504"
    },
    "contatos" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55aaa7d644aeceb9f439c504/contatos"
    },
    "agencias" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55aaa7d644aeceb9f439c504/agencias"
    }
  }
}
```

## *Associações de URI*


No momento em que crio um veículo, não consigo enviar um Array de Agências/Veículos porque são atributos de **referência** que foram declarados com a anotação `@DBRef` e estes possuem seus próprios resources (*/api/contatos* e */api/agencias*), o qual não faria sentido algum isso. O que é preciso para solucionar o meu problema é:
1. Criar uma agência no resource de agência e contato no resource de contato
2. Criar um veículo e relacionar com as agẽncias e contatos criados

**Atenção**
Eu obtinha um `InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException` após criar a associação pois no meu caso o default é o banco ser executado em memória, após as associações eu simplesmente não conseguia acessar os paths. Para executar com o banco, basta executar `mvn spring-boot:run` no diretório.

#### *Bancos relacionais*


Somente para bancos relacionais, tem de se verificar o relacionamento e como irá associar.

#### *Bancos não-relacionais*


Não é necessário especificar como será o relacionamento, como diz na referência da API:

> There's no need to use something like @OneToMany because the mapping
>   framework sees that you're wanting a one-to-many relationship because
>   there is a List of objects. When the object is stored in MongoDB,
>   there will be a list of DBRefs rather than the Account objects
>   themselves.

Para associar, basta passar no array as URI's de agência:

POST /veiculos

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '"nome": "Veiculo", "tipo": "tipo", "agencias": ["http://localhost:8181/api/agencias/55ae37edccf2070af2e5ab1d", "http://localhost:8181/api/agencias/55ae37e8ccf2070af2e5ab1c"]}' localhost:8181/api/veiculos
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55ae3813ccf2070af2e5ab1e
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 12:16:19 GMT

{
  "nome" : "Veiculo",
  "tipo" : "tipo",
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55ae3813ccf2070af2e5ab1e"
    },
    "contatos" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55ae3813ccf2070af2e5ab1e/contatos"
    },
    "agencias" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55ae3813ccf2070af2e5ab1e/agencias"
    }
  }
}
```

GET para verificar a associação

```
daniela.morais@tusk:~$ curl -i -X GET http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55ae383ccf2070af2e5ab1e/agencias
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 21 Jul 2015 12:16:45 GMT

{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/veiculos/55ae3813ccf2070af2e5ab1e/agencias"
    }
  },
  "_embedded" : {
    "agencias" : [ {
      "nome" : "Agencia dois",
      "createdBy" : "anonymousUser",
      "lastModifiedBy" : "anonymousUser",
      "createdAt" : "2015-07-21T12:15:41.286+0000",
      "lastModified" : "2015-07-21T12:15:41.286+0000",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/agencias/55ae37edccf2070af2e5ab1d"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "nome" : "Agencia um",
      "createdBy" : "anonymousUser",
      "lastModifiedBy" : "anonymousUser",
      "createdAt" : "2015-07-21T12:15:36.369+0000",
      "lastModified" : "2015-07-21T12:15:36.369+0000",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8181/api/agencias/55ae37e8ccf2070af2e5ab1c"
        }
      }
    } ]
  }
```

Um [exemplo](http://recursivechaos.com/blog/spring-data-mongodb-dbref/) mais simples de associação com mongoDB. 
É possível também associar enviando um PUT/POST com a uri-list, **independente** do banco: 
I. [POSTing a @OneToMany sub-resource association in Spring Data REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311978/posting-a-onetomany-sub-resource-ass%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bociation-in-spring-data-rest/25451662#25451662)
II. [Spring Data REST: Silent failure when adding entity relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129650/spring-data-rest-silent-failure-when-adding-entity-relationship)
III. [Exposing Spring Data repositories over REST](http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/10/exposing-spring-data-repositories-over-rest.html)

Apesar de simples a solução, deixo aqui links da Sensedia sobre API's que me ajudaram a compreender meu problema
I. [Webinar: Os Fundamentos da Segurança de APIs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h4A8HytL5ts)
II. [Webinar Design de APIs RESTful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psLrAsdHltQ)