# Como testar a API Restful?

Tags: web-service, api, asp.net-web-api

Olá, estou estagiando e o rapaz criou uma AP e mandou eu fazer os métodos http de post,delete e etc.. Eu gostaria de saber se está correto o que eu fiz e o código dele, e como eu faço para testa-lo.

**config.js**

```
//qualidade
//var urlBO = 'http://Z1T1BRMXVTA56.br.batgen.com:6405';
var urlBO = 'http://10.92.215.128:6405';

//produção
//var urlBO = 'http://10.0.100.64:6405';


var allowed_users = [
    {
    user:   "mATCPT77",
    nome:   "",
    email:  ""
    },
    {
    user:   "matvdbtt",
    nome:   "",
    email:  ""
    },
    {
    user:   "matfimgo",
    nome:   "",
    email:  ""
    },
    {
    user:   "81242726",
    nome:   "",
    email:  ""
    },
    {
    user:   "matvdpms",
    nome:   "",
    email:  ""
    },
    {
    user:   "cipvdbco",
    nome:   "",
    email:  ""
    },
    {
    user:   "81233167",
    nome:   "",
    email:  ""
    },
    {
    user:   "81260372",
    nome:   "",
    email:  ""
    },
    {
    user:   "matvdjpa",
    nome:   "",
    email:  ""
    },
    {
    user:   "81232993",
    nome:   "",
    email:  ""
    }
];

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://10.92.215.128:6405/api/:users/:id',
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    sucess: function(data) {
        console.log("Usuário encontrado", data); // Retorna todos os usuários.
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://10.92.215.128:6405/api/:users/:id',
    data: {id: '', user: '', nome: '', email: ''},
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    sucess: function(data) {
        console.log("Usuário criado com sucesso!", data); // O novo usuário é criado com uma nova ID.
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    data: {id: '', user: '', nome: '', email: ''},
    url: 'http://10.92.215.128:6405/api/:users/:id',
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    sucess: function() {
        // Sem data, apenas um código de sucesso (200).
        console.log("Usuário atualizado com sucesso!"); // Atualiza o usuário.
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'DELETE',
    data: {id: '', user: '', nome: '', email: ''},
    url: 'http://10.92.215.128:6405/api/:users/:id',
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    sucess: function() {
        // Sem data, apenas um código de sucesso (200).
        console.log("Usuário deletado com sucesso com sucesso!"); 
    }
});
```

**bo_restful.js**

```
/***********************************************************************************
Gravar a sessão cookie
***********************************************************************************/
    function writeSession(name, value) {
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined")
            localStorage.setItem(name, value);
        else
            window.location.href = "index.html?msg=Seu navegador não suporta 'Web Storage', procure o administrador do sistema.";
    }
/***********************************************************************************
Ler a sessão cookie
***********************************************************************************/
    function readSession(name) {
        if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            return localStorage.getItem(name);
        }else{
            window.location.href = "index.html?msg=Seu navegador não suporta 'Web Storage', procure o administrador do sistema.";
            return "";
        }
    }
/***********************************************************************************
Criação do ajax CORS
***********************************************************************************/
    function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
            // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
            // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
            xhr.open(method, url, false);
        } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
            // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
            // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
            xhr = new XDomainRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
            xhr = null;
        }
        return xhr;
    }
/***********************************************************************************
LOGIN
***********************************************************************************/
    function doLogon(auth, user, pass){
        //valida se os campos estão preenchidos
        if ((user != "") && (pass != "")) {
            //loading(true);
            if (getObjetoUsers(user) != "" && getObjetoUsers(user) != "undefined" && getObjetoUsers(user) != null){
                var body = '<?xml version="1.0"?><attrs xmlns="http://www.sap.com/rws/bip"><attr name="userName" type="string">'+ 
                            user + '</attr><attr name="password" type="string">' + 
                            pass + '</attr><attr name="auth" type="string" possibilities="secEnterprise,secLDAP,secWinAD">' + auth + '</attr></attrs>';
                var response;
                var logonToken;
                var urlBip = urlBO + "/biprws/logon/long";
                var logon = createCORSRequest('POST', urlBip, false);
                if (!logon) console.log('Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) not supported', 'error');
                //logon.open('POST', urlBip, false);
                logon.setRequestHeader('X-PINGARUNER', 'pingpong');
                logon.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
                logon.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/xml');
                logon.send(body);
                if (logon.readyState == 4 && logon.status == 200) {
                    logonToken = logon.getResponseHeader('X-SAP-LogonToken');
                    token = logonToken;
                    logonToken = logonToken.substring(1,logonToken.length-1);
                    logonToken = logonToken.trim();
                    writeSession("logonToken", '"'+logonToken+'"');
                    writeSession("user", user);
                    var timeStamp = +new Date;
                    window.location.href = "wds.html?t=" +new Date;
                } else {
                    if (auth == "secWinAD"){
                        console.log("Tentativa de conectar usando secWinAD falhou: " + logon.responseXML);
                        doLogon("secEnterprise", user, pass);
                    }else{
                        window.location.href = "index.html?msg=Falha na autenticação com o SAP, entre em contato com o administrador do sistema caso este problema se repita (readyState:" + logon.readyState + " status:" + logon.status + ").";
                    }
                }
            }else{
                window.location.href = "index.html?msg=Permissão negada ao usuário '" + user + "'.";
            }
        } else {
              window.location.href = "index.html?msg=As informações de Login e Senha são obrigatórias.";
        }
    }
/***********************************************************************************
LOGOFF
***********************************************************************************/
    function doLogoff(){
        if (confirm("Deseja realmente encerrar sua sessão?")) {
            var token = readSession("logonToken")
            var urlBip = urlBO + "/biprws/logoff";
            var logoff = createCORSRequest('POST', urlBip, false);
            if (!logoff) console.log('Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) not supported', 'error');
            //logoff.open('POST', urlBip, false);
            logoff.send();
            localStorage.removeItem("user");
            localStorage.removeItem("logonToken");
            window.location.href = "index.html?msg=Sua sessão foi finalizada com sucesso.";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Há várias maneiras de realizar testes de APIs, uma maneira fácil e prática é usar frameworks e para testes automatizados desenvolver scripts.

***Postman e Swagger***

O [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) e o [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) são ferramentas gratuitas onde é possível documentar a API e testá-la, é útil pois possibilita enviar JSONs com headers específicos apenas completando os campos e clicar em "Enviar" sem a necessidade de nenhum código e possui históricos de testes.

Para utilizar o Swagger, geralmente o desenvolvedor da API utiliza as anotações apropriadas e a documentação e paths são gerados automaticamente. O link é disponibilizado para todos os desenvolvedores ou publicamente (caso hajam aplicações terceiras que podem acessar), geralmente *localhost:8080/minha_aplicacao/swagger*

[Exemplo de documentação de API com Swagger](http://petstore.swagger.io/)

No seu caso, provavelmente o desenvolvedor não disponibilizou a documentação com o Swagger então sugiro utilizar o Postman.

No postman, selecione o tipo de HTTP Request (GET, POST, PUT etc), adicione na aba de Headers o contentType correspondente, na aba Body selecione a opção Raw e JSON(application/json) e cole o seu JSON neste campo.

***Resources***

A URL da sua API está como *10.92.215.128:6405/api/:users/:id* e por esse seu trecho de código, acredito que pode haver uma confusão sobre APIs.

Resources são implementados como substantivos e possuem sua própria lógica e algumas vezes até **banco de dados ou servidor específico** (microserviços estão aí!). *Users* é um tipo de resource e pelo padrão REST temos que a URL da sua API deve ser acessada como (ou deveria ser numa boa implementação de API Rest):

/api/users/{id}

No caso *{id}*, é um tipo de pathParam e o ID deve ser passado pela URL.

***CURL***

Outra forma que pode ser útil e comumente encontrada em documentações é realizar testes através do terminal. Exemplo de como realizar uma requisição GET para o User que possui ID 1:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" "10.92.215.128:6405/api/users/1"
```

***Afinal, e no caso do seu script?***

Você já possui um script JS pronto e caso acredite que seja a solução mais adequada, o mais útil seria associar o seu **config.js** com alguma página .html e usar o inspector para debuggar os outputs e códigos de retorno obtidos.

**Links interessantes**

[O que é uma arquitetura de microserviços?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68899/o-que-%C3%A9-uma-arquitetura-de-microservi%C3%A7os)

[Requisições para API Rest](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/74631/requisi%c3%a7%c3%b5es-para-api-rest/75499#75499)

[When to use @QueryParam vs @PathParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552248/when-to-use-queryparam-vs-pathparam)